# Expecting to get client sides' username by calling `req.body.username`. However, calling `req.body` returns a weird formatted String

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, axios, routes

The problem is that when I call `req.body` in my server, it returns a weird formatted string rather than a JSON object

[image]

I am expecting to get it as a JSON object as I have passed it as such from the client side:

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = "http://localhost:4000/signup";
    var credentials = JSON.stringify({
        "username": e.target[0].value,
        "email": e.target[1].value,
        "password": e.target[2].value
    })
    const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: credentials,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    }
    console.log('@singup credentials:', credentials)  // <----- CONSOLE LOGS THATS PRINTED
    try {
        const resp = await axios(config)
        console.log('data:',resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.log('at signup post error:')
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

My server code is:

```
app.route("/signup")
.post((req, res) => {
    console.log("req.body:")
    console.log(req.body) // <----- CONSOLE LOGS THATS PRINTED
    var user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    });
    user.save((err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('signup POST req fail from /signup endpoint')
            res.send("error in signpu post")
        } else {
            req.session.user = docs;
            res.redirect("/dashboard");
        }
    });
});
```

The logs I see from client side and server side are as follows:

[image]

[image]

I do have the encoding turned on in my server code as such:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
```

To be more specific on my problem:

- Why do I not get the `req.body` as a JSON object in my server side? I understand that I'm passing the data as "www-form-urlencoded", so do I need to encode and decode from client/server side to read the passing data as JSON? I wish to call `req.body.username` in my nodejs backend to get the username that was passed from the frontend.
- Adding/Removing `JSON.stringify` from the client side has no effect here, shouldn't it?

If you need further information on the project, please comment below and I'll edit the post to include the asking info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is JSON-encoded, you need to use the correct content type in your request:

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
```

Or, even easier, let Axios take care of it (because it defaults to JSON):

```
const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  method: 'post',
  url:    url,
  data:   {
    username: e.target[0].value,
    email:    e.target[1].value,
    password: e.target[2].value
  }
}
```